# data.table operations on columns

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to do some operations on a list of columns in a data.table.
I put here an example. In fact I have around 30 variables in the data.table (DT). that is why there are some lines for running a loop on the variables I am interested in.
As I would like to preserve the input DT I do a copy with DT2 <- DT to operate on it.
Eventually this could be done on the initial one DT.
The error message says:

> *Error in eval(DT[, (var)]) * eval(DT[, variable6]) :     non-numeric
>   argument to binary operator*

I did not find an appropriate answer on the forum yet.
Sorry for the presentation of my question. Not used to!

thanks for help.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(
  variable1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
  variable2 = 1:5,
  variable3 = c(1, 2, 5, 6, 8),
  variable4 = c(1, 2, 5, 6, 8),
  variable5 = c(1, 2, 5, 6, 8),
  variable6 = c(12, 14, 18, 100, 103),
  variable7 = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02))
cols = sapply(DT, is.numeric)
cols = cols[-c(6, 7)]
cols = names(cols)[cols]
DT2 <- DT
for(var in cols) {
  DT2[, (var)] == eval(DT[, (var)]) * eval(DT[, variable6]) / eval(DT[variable7])
}
```

Comment: Please make sure you add the appropriate language tag to your questions. Also, I think you just want `for (vars in cols) DT2[, (vars) := get(vars) * variable6 / variable7]`. Also, don't add malicious code such as `rm(list = ls())` to your questions. Finally, please be careful with stuff such as `DT2 <- DT` (see `?copy`)

Comment: thank you @DavidArenburg

Comment: It happens I have some 0 value for variable 7. Where then to include sort of a (sapply(.SD, is.infinite) statement to avoid getting many "Inf" ?

Comment: Btw, you could also do ```DT2[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, `*`, variable6 / variable7), .SDcols = cols]``` (without the for loop).